# Not seeing shell prompt or input when running docker exec from a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, terminal, docker-compose

So this is weird and maybe kind of hard to explain - but when I run a `docker exec xxx bash` command from make/Makefile I cannot see the shell prompt or anything I type until after I press enter.

Example Makefile

```
docker-shell:
    docker-compose exec web bash
```

When I run `make docker-shell` it connects but the shell prompt doesn't appear until I press  once. I can type input and submit it but the characters don't show up until I press  again. If I run the `docker-compose` command directly everything works.

This is in a tmux session inside iTerm but I have tried in native OSX terminal too. Strange...

Comment: I'm surprised that works at all; I would have expected that `make` wouldn't plumb stdin through to its child processes. Seems like an unnecessary source of fragility for a build system to allow things it starts to depend on terminal input.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interesting - I do agree that using make act as a "bash playbook" is not what it was intended for, and that's how we're using it here. My "real" makefile is much more complicated than the one I posted too but I simplified for the purposes of the question. I can see the use for tty/terminal input for things like passwords or other inputs though. Regardless the issue I had was that I was using grc and that interfered with the tty somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh blimey - I'm dumb. In case anyone encounters this the issue is I had make aliased to use a tool called [colourify/grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc). So:

```
$ which make
make: aliased to colourify make
```

If I run `/usr/bin/make` directly everything works. I suppose this is maybe a bug with grc but at least I/you know that's the culprit now.